# Why I can't see up to date logs in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have deployed a GAE/Java application and an error occurred when trying to access the application from web browser. However when I checked the logs in appspot console, it's almost 2 hours old. I cannot see the recent logs even after refreshing the page multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes wrong from time to time. The only thing(s) you can do are :

1) Log a support issue (officially - this is the only thing you can do)

2) Join the IRC channel and see if anybody else is experiencing the same problem (sometimes the googlers hang out on here)

3) Find the app engine developers on google+, twitter etc and prod them there (WARNING: It better be urgent to follow this route btw).

4) Oh... make sure you are viewing the right "version" of the app in the log viewer too !

Comment: Your suggestions makes sense. I think the first step would be to report an issue in the bug tracker. #4 doesn't have any significance since I have only one version in appspot.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have selected the show 'All requests' option at the top of the logs page in the admin console? By default it will only show 'Logs with minimum severity: error'.

Comment: Yes. I just tried the application from the browser and it failed with an error. But in the logs it shows the entries till 14:25 (current time is 15:27)

Answer (score 0):

You probably changed the major version name of the app when you deployed most recently, and now you're viewing logs for the old version. Select the correct version from the pulldown in the top left.

Comment: Currently, I have only one version.